# Flash Prompt in symfony 5

Tags: symfony

I can't find anything about flash prompt in Symfony 5 documentation.
Is there a way to make a statement with the same outcome as this statement in Symfony 2:

```
$this->get('session.flashprompt')->add(
   'Would you like to send an email confirmation to the customer?',
   $this->generateUrl('some route', array('id' =>$id, 'message' =>     
   confirmation'))
);
```

**Update**
I assumed that this was part of symfony2 but it was provided by a bundle: bootstrap-bundle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 5 still has this feature, except now you have to use the `session` service:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add($type, $message);
```

If you're in a controller that extends `AbstractController`, you can still use the `addFlash()` method. It executes the same code under the hood.

Comment: I am glad to hear that flash prompt is still available. What would be the type in this case? I tried 'flashprompt' it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like it's an arbitrary string that helps you group your flash messages. See the example in the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages

Comment: A useful purpose of the "type" is to apply a CSS class to your flash message. For example if your front end were to be using Bootstrap, then the type could be "info", "success", "warning", or "danger" to make CSS classes "alert-info", etc. -- Very up to you though.

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear, the question is how to do flash prompts in Symfony 5 not flash messages in general. In case it is not clear flash prompt is the flash message that prompts (asks) the user to confirm or cancel a transaction for example. It needs input from the user. Hope this clarifies better the original question.

Comment: I don't think this was ever a Symfony 2 feature. Sounds like a custom bundle that you might have been using. The only result that google returns about `session.flashprompt` is this very question.

Comment: @Barstoz, you are right it was bootstrap-bundle. Ypdated this question. Thanks!

Comment: Then you know the answer to your question. Symfony 5 doesn't have this feature and never had it, so either use the bundle that you used for it back then, or implement the feature yourself if the bundle is incompatible with Symfony 5. Or find another bundle.